# Can Dialogflow respond with Video?

Tags: dialogflow-es

Can Dialogflow respond with Video? I wished to have a video triggered as an intent response but I think there is no way out within the selection.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Through custom payload. You can attach a [video type response](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/integrations/facebook) like in the case of facebook messenger

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. According to [the documentation](https://dialogflow.com/docs/intents/responses), the intent response could be a static text or [Webhook response](https://dialogflow.com/docs/fulfillment/how-it-works), which is a JSON. You may consider to provide a link of the video in the response so the user can get it by clicking it.